# When to know if I am "on the right track" for a CNN architecture

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, image-segmentation, architecture

**Context**

Very new to CNNs and ML in general. I am building a simple binary image segmentation network for generating black and white image masks (white pixels = desired object; black pixels = all else). To this end, I am taking a downsampling/upsampling approach utilizing convolutions and max pooling to downsample, and then transposed convolution to upsample.

My network does extremely well on the training data, mastering it in under 50 epochs, but struggles with the test set. I know that the best ways to mitigate overfitting are reducing complexity, regularization, data augmentation, etc. but I'm really struggling to find that sweet spot between not learning at all and essentially memorizing the test set. I'm aware that a lot of building a robust architecture is mostly empirical.

**My question(s)**

How can I know if a high-level framework such as the depth or number of filters/kernels in a given convolution, as opposed to smaller tweaks such as hyperparameter tuning or dropout, is "close" to capturing the essence of the task? Is it a "good sign" that my model, despite aggressively overfitting, is able to capture patterns that I'm interested in? Or is it possible that my approach is inherently inadequate for the task?

**TL;DR**

Is overfitting, as opposed to not learning, a sign that I'm headed in the right direction, architecturally speaking?

Comment: It is always good to first attempt to overfit your architecture on a very simple dataset to ensure that your architecture can actually learn something to the extend that you want it. I know of many data scientists that they can often take 10 samples to overfit their models, just to see whether they can. It might not necessarily mean your code is bug free, but it assures you that you are on the right track. There is nothing wrong with this approach. I've even fitted generative time-series models on the standard base sine curve. You might try a single digit from MNIST for example.